# C#: How to check a value and convert an imperial value to metric if necessary?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Just a heads up: I'm an absolute beginner so I need this broken down for me.

**Q:**  **This method is suppose to *check* and see if mostRecentMeasure is Metric, and if its not, its suppose to convert it to Metric. How can I compare mostRecentMeasure to Metric? Given this specific example, how would I convert mostRecentMeasure to Metric if mostRecentMeasure isn't Metric?**

The code I wrote so far:

```
class MeasureLengthDevice : IMeasuringDevice
{
    
    private double unitsToUse; 
    private int dataCaptured;
    private int mostRecentMeasure;
    private double convertToMetric;


    // initializes fields.
    public MeasureLengthDevice(double unitsToUse, int dataCaptured, int mostRecentMeasure)
    {
        this.unitsToUse = unitsToUse;
        this.dataCaptured = dataCaptured;
        this.mostRecentMeasure = mostRecentMeasure;
    }

    /*MetricValue method comes from IMeasuringDevice interface.*/
    public decimal MetricValue(decimal Metric) 
    {
        return mostRecentMeasure;
        if  (mostRecentMeasure != Metric)
        {
            convertToMetric = mostRecentMeasure * 2.54;
        }

    }
```

Comment: How would you know if the value is metric or not?

Comment: Thats my question. @LasseV.Karlsen

Comment: A `decimal` has no knowledge of this. If that is all you have, then it's not possible. You will need additional information from the source of that value to know which unit it is in or whether it is metric or not (whatever that actually means).

Comment: Does IMeasuringDevice pass in a unit (kg, lbs, c, f) along with the data?  If so, use that to determine whether or not the data is metric.